# Comparing js dates ... what week is it?

Tags: javascript

Thanks for looking at this. Javascript dates always mess me over.

I am running a time defined event and each week define new functionality. In my js I have the following;

```js
var challenge_start = new Date(2018,03,14);
var today = new Date(2018,4,1)
var int = new Date();
var weekNo = 0;
  
 if(today<=int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 7)) {
  weekNo = 1;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 7) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 15)) {
  weekNo = 2;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 14) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 22)) {
  weekNo = 3;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 21) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 29)) {
  weekNo = 4;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 28) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 36)) {
  weekNo = 5;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 35) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 43)) {
  weekNo = 6;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 42) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 49)) {
  weekNo = 7;
 }
 console.log(weekNo);
```

Today, I would expect weekNo=3 but instead I get weekNo=1. What am I missing here? There must be a better way to do this?

Thanks for looking at it,

Comment: https://momentjs.com/ will do this much better than you can

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but what will probably trip you up... `new Date(2018,03,14)` is 14th April 2018 - not March as you probably expect.

Comment: What is `weekNo` supposed to measure/represent?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The week

Comment: @Feathercrown: **What** week?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The week after the challenge start date.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, looking for the number of weeks since the challenge start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to admit that I have trouble following your logic and what it is you ultimately want to know, but one thing jumped out at me: You're setting the day-of-month (`setDate`) on `int` based on `getDate` from `challenge_start` when they are in different months entirely (because `int` was initialized with just `new Date()`).

If I change it so `int` and `challenge_start` are initially the same date:

```
var int = new Date(challenge_start.getTime());
```

...your code returns `3` as you seem to expect:

```js
var challenge_start = new Date(2018,03,14);
var today = new Date(2018,4,1)
var int = new Date(challenge_start.getTime());
var weekNo = 0;
  
 if(today<=int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 7)) {
  weekNo = 1;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 7) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 15)) {
  weekNo = 2;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 14) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 22)) {
  weekNo = 3;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 21) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 29)) {
  weekNo = 4;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 28) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 36)) {
  weekNo = 5;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 35) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 43)) {
  weekNo = 6;
 }
 if(today>int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 42) && today< int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 49)) {
  weekNo = 7;
 }
 console.log(weekNo);
```

**If** `weekNo` is meant to be "how many weeks between the challenge start and now?" then the simplest thing is probably just to get the milliseconds between the two dates and divide by a week's worth of milliseconds, rounding up (as you appear to count partial weeks):

```js
var challenge_start = new Date(2018,03,14);
var today = new Date(2018,4,1); // I assume this is a stand-in for just `new Date()`

today.setHours(0, 0, 0);            // Note making sure to get rid of the time (well, using midnight)
challenge_start.setHours(0, 0, 0);  // Note the midnight thing again
var weekNo = Math.ceil((today - challenge_start) / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log(weekNo);
```

That works because JavaScript's `Date` treats a day as *exactly* 86400000 (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) milliseconds.

Comment: This helps greatly ... thank you! I was looking for the number of weeks since the challenge started and now.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly easy to calculate, no need for look ups.

Subtracting one date from another will get you the difference in ms between the two dates. Divide this by the number of milliseconds per week (1000*60*60*24*7 = 604,800,000) will get you the number of weeks since the start date.

This is not the same as week number so round it down and add 1.

```js
var challengeStart = new Date(2018,03,14);
var today = new Date(2018,4,1)

const weeksSince = (start, date) => {
  
  const msPerWeek = 604800000;
  
  return Math.floor((date - start) / msPerWeek) + 1
};

var weekNo = weeksSince(challengeStart, today);

console.log("Week No. " + weekNo);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.getDate()` simply returns the nth of the month - today, it returns 1.

It seems like you want to know how many weeks have passed since the challenge_start date.
Try the following:

```
function getWeeksSince(date)
{
   return Math.floor((new Date() - date) / 604800000); //604800000 is the amount of ms in a week
}
getWeeksSince(challenge_start); //2
```

This will return 2 when anywhere between 2-3 weeks have passed.
As soon as 3 full weeks have passed since April 14th (which will be on May 5th) it will return 3.

Answer (score -2):

TL;DR; - you're comparing "ticks" instead of days.

Since `today` is a Date object, where int.setDate() returns a number - the number of ticks since epoch, to be exact.  To do the comparison, the language converts `today` to a number of ticks, based on "00:00:00".

When I ran my test version, I got `int.setDate(challenge_start.getDate() + 7) == 1526912465737`, where `today.valueOf() == 1525154400000`

As suggested elsewhere, you could use a secondary library like moment (I'm a particular fan of [sugar.js](https://sugarjs.com/)).  Or if you want to stay with "pure" javascript, you could convert those ticks to days using a bunch of math.

Comment: Could the downvoters please tell me what about my response deserved a downvote?